# How to add uibarbutton programatically on uitoolbar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

[image]

This is my `UIToolbar`,I would like to add `Twitter` and `Whatsapp UIBarbutton` into one.

I googled but I am only getting information for `UINavigationController`.

Is there any predefined method ,or I need to customize it?

Comment: just add UIButton on toolbar & set image accordingly.

Comment: @Gagan_iOS so there is no predefined function for this ,we need to customize it correct ?

Comment: you want to add two images in single barbutton,

Comment: even you can add images on bar button/UIbutton while adding on Storyboard.

Comment: oh ok @Anbu.Karthik bro ,i will try it,then how i have to handle the twitter and whatsapp sharing in single button action .

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik both are different action ,so no possible to combine it .i like to add the two uibarbuttom item to one ,is there any way bro.

Comment: then do like set the tags for each barbuttonItem , it is easy to handle ,

Comment: @Kishore use same action in code but assign different tag values for twitter and facebook buttons. Based on that tag value you can perform your actions accordingly .

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik ok bro.

Comment: @MuhammadAdnan ok bro i will try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do like

```
UIBarButtonItem *TwitterButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit target:self action:@selector(SocialAction:)];
TwitterButtonItem.tag = 1;

UIBarButtonItem *WhatsAppButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSave target:self action:@selector(SocialAction:)];
WhatsAppButtonItem.tag = 2;

yourtoolBar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:WhatsAppButtonItem,TwitterButtonItem, nil];
```

get like

```
- (Void)SocialAction:(UIBarButtonItem *)button {
NSLog(@"%i", button.tag);
 // based on tag continue your work
}
```

Comment: if i do like this bro ,my other story board items not visible.

Comment: other storyboard items means other uibarbutton added through the storyboard

Comment: what ever you did thats is good, just use the tags for each object it is easy to solve